# matching and extracting text with python and regex

Tags: text, pattern-matching, expression

I'm trying to extract text from a log file, match on a group then extract and output a specific error in a text file.

> ----static title Start ----
>   lots of junk in here [128587] [date] Missing important
>   more junk same same same Missing important.Test.beta
>   so much junk same same same Missing important.update.package
>   random information here Missing important.old
>   ----static title End----

Initially I tried

> ----static\stitle\sStart----(\n.+)\n----static\stitle\sEnd---

which will group and extract all of text to a new  result text file file trouble is I only need the specific variables that appear after Missing and extract them to a text file they either appear as single words or appended with full points '.' before the next word.

> important
>   important.update.package
>   important.Test.beta
>   important.old

I'm looking to match on what appears after missing and output it as a list.

> (?<=Missing)\s+\w+.+?\w+?.+?|\w+?.+?

As its a list I probably need a carriage return in here too still work in progress.

Regards,

Arc

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to this myself.

```
[(^Missing)](\s+\w+\.?[^\s]+)
```

Matches on first whitespace and words with optional '.' between each word up until the next whitespace!